# How to convert hex into ascii hex string in python?

Tags: python, c++, string, hex

Hi I'm learning pySerial module, so the hex to ascii is its fundamental.

So far I have the following concepts.

Byte String: "\xde"

Byte Array:

```
>>> bytearray('\xde')
bytearray(b'\xde')
>>> a = bytearray('\xde')
>>> a[0]
222
>>> hex(a[0])
'0xde'
```

Hex String: '\xde'

Hex: 0xde

Normal representation: de

Now what I need is Hex String to Hex and vice versa.

Also Hex or Hex String to Normal representation .

I wish I can have the simplest possible answer.

**Update:**

I think I got an initial answer other than string operation.
But this looks really dirty.

```
>>> hex(int(binascii.hexlify('\xde'),16))
'0xde'
```

Comment: "... pySerial module, so the hex to ascii is its fundamental." What? No, this makes no sense.

Comment: well, it requires lots of hex signal indeed.

Comment: No, not really. It's usually very rare to need the hexadecimal representation.

Comment: Have you tried: int('de',16) to convert '\xde' to decimal?

Comment: >>> int('\xde',16)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '\xde'

Answer (score 1):

Let me re-write a little.

You have a byte (say `b`, with an integer value of 222 (in decimal) or de (in hexadecimal) or 276 in octal or 10111110 in binary.

Its hexadecimal string representation is `'0xde'`

The following initialisations are the same :

```
b = 222
b = 0xde
```

Here are the conversions (say `s` is a string, `s='0xde'`, ie the hexadecimal string representation)

```
s = hex(b)
b = int(s, 16)
```

Edit per comment :

If you *really* want to be able to accept as input `\xde` as well as `0xde` you can do :

```
b = int('0' + s[1:] if (s[0] == '\\') else s, 16)
```

or directly

```
b = int('0' + s[1:], 16)
```

if you are sure you will never get *weird* input

Comment: You are right, but why would you want to use such a representation ? The *correct* hexadecimal string representation for 222 is `0xde`, `\xde` is only the way to write an arbitrary byte value into  a string as a synonym for `\00de`, or to write it directly into a bytearray.